A Mapping on $\mathbb{Z}/n \mathbb{Z}$
Good people!
The question I have for you concerns Lamé's (failed) proof of Fermat's Last Theorem, specifically, it concerns an implicit lemma that Lamé's 1847 article contains that this French savant does not actually prove, and it's driving me crazy, because I cannot prove it myself either.
It has previously been mentioned in another question of Stack Exchange on Lamé's proof, in a very meticulous answer given by a fellow by the name of Jack M. You can find that response here:
What was Lame's proof?
The statement is as follows:

If a subset of $\mathbb{Z} / n \mathbb{Z}$ ($n$ being a prime greater than two) contains at least two elements and is closed under the operation $(k,j) \mapsto 2k-j$ for $k \neq j$ then it is equal to all of $\mathbb{Z} / n \mathbb{Z}$.

Jack M states that they are not certain if this lemma is actually true, but playing around with a Python script, for every input I give it, it delivers an affirmative result. (If $n=23$ and the subset contains 4 and 11, then it contains all of $\mathbb{Z} / 23 \mathbb{Z}$, if $n=47$ and the subset contains 9 and 22, then it contains all of $\mathbb{Z} / 47 \mathbb{Z}$, if $n=51$ and the subset contains 4 and 8, then it contains all of $\mathbb{Z} / 51 \mathbb{Z}$, etc., etc.)
I've tried playing around with this now to and fro in the background for the past couple of days, and I'm getting nowhere.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

This lemma is proved in a comment under the answer you cite.
